# How to match and replace a subset of column names

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace some (but not all) column names in a dataframe with more descriptive labels.
I have a vector with longnames and need to match and replace the current relevant column names.

In more detail:

I have a dataframe with columns that are both text and numeric.
Eg

```
df<-data.frame(text1=c("nnnn","uuuu","ooo"),
               text2=c("b","t","eee"),
               a1=c(1,2,3),
               a2=c(45,43,23),
               b1=c(43,6,2),
               text3=c("gg","ll","jj"))
```

So it looks like this:

```
df
  text1 text2 a1 a2 b1 text3
1  nnnn     b  1 45 43    gg
2  uuuu     t  2 43  6    ll
3   ooo   eee  3 23  2    jj
```

I also have a vector of longer labels for some of the column labels:

```
longnames=c("a1 age","a2 gender","b1 postcode")
```

Where there is a matching long name, I would like to completely replace the corresponding short names in df. So my desired output is:

```
  text1 text2 a1 age a2 gender b1 postcode text3
1  nnnn     b      1        45          43    gg
2  uuuu     t      2        43           6    ll
3   ooo   eee      3        23           2    jj
```

All of the short labels that need to be replaced uniquely match the start of the relevant long label. In other words, the short label "**a2**" needs to be replaced by the long label "**a2 gender**" and this long label is the only long label that starts with "**a2**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::rename` can rename a subset of columns in one go but it needs a named vector for the new names.

```r
library("tidyverse")

df <- data.frame(
  text1 = c("nnnn", "uuuu", "ooo"),
  text2 = c("b", "t", "eee"),
  a1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  a2 = c(45, 43, 23),
  b1 = c(43, 6, 2),
  text3 = c("gg", "ll", "jj")
)

longnames <- c("a1 age", "a2 gender", "b1 postcode")
shortnames <- str_extract(longnames, "^(\\w+)")

# named vector specifying how to rename
names(shortnames) <- longnames
shortnames
#>      a1 age   a2 gender b1 postcode 
#>        "a1"        "a2"        "b1"

df %>%
  rename(!!shortnames)
#>   text1 text2 a1 age a2 gender b1 postcode text3
#> 1  nnnn     b      1        45          43    gg
#> 2  uuuu     t      2        43           6    ll
#> 3   ooo   eee      3        23           2    jj

# In this case `!!shortnames` achieves this:

df %>%
  rename("a1 age" = "a1",
         "a2 gender" = "a2",
         "b1 postcode" = "b1")
#>   text1 text2 a1 age a2 gender b1 postcode text3
#> 1  nnnn     b      1        45          43    gg
#> 2  uuuu     t      2        43           6    ll
#> 3   ooo   eee      3        23           2    jj
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Specifying the new names programatically is useful because we can more easily and cleanly change the column name specifications. But for more readability you can start at first with the explicit specification, it is just more writing.

Comment: Could you explain what the '!!' means?

Comment: This is an example of "tidy evaluation". A big topic that you can read more about here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: In this particular case `!!` helps to pass along the column name vector (which specifies pairs of old names and new names) to the `rename` function.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations!
To actually change the names in df, the final line needs to be:
df <- df %>% rename (!!shortnames)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it by using `sapply`. This can be done using `for` loop as well with almost exact code.  `seq.int(colnames(df))` produces a sequence of 1:`ncol(df)`.  `grep` finds the index in `longnames` when there is a match of respective column name from `df`.  Then `if` condition checks if the length of index vector is > 0 (which should be if there is a column match).  Then it makes the replacement.

```
## sapply (can be replaced with lapply)
sapply(seq.int(colnames(df)), function(x) {
  index <- grep(colnames(df)[x], longnames)
  if (length(index) > 0) colnames(df)[x] <<- longnames[index]
})
```

OR

```
## for loop (note the difference in <<-)
for (x in seq.int(colnames(df))) {
  index <- grep(colnames(df)[x], longnames)
  if (length(index) > 0) colnames(df)[x] <- longnames[index]
}
```

Comment: This is close but doesnt quite work. It results in a list with 6 elements, the entries that dont match any longnames are NULL. I'm interested in what is happening in this code though, can you say what each line is doing?

Comment: Added the explanation. There was an error in the later part of `if` statement line. Fixed now and it should work. It still might some output with NULL on the console but that's only for the columns where there was no match, The `df` columns are updated simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

```
m1 = sapply(names(df), function(snm) sapply(longnames, function(lnm) grepl(snm, lnm)))
df1 = setNames(df, replace(names(df), colSums(m1) == 1, longnames[rowSums(m1) == 1]))
df1
#  text1 text2 a1 age a2 gender b1 postcode text3
#1  nnnn     b      1        45          43    gg
#2  uuuu     t      2        43           6    ll
#3   ooo   eee      3        23           2    jj
```

`m1` is a matrix showing the matches between column names of `df` and `longnames`. `colSums(m1) == 1` identifies the column names that have a match. `rowSums(m1) == 1` identifies the respective matching `longnames`.

OR use partial match

```
inds = pmatch(colnames(df), longnames)
df1 = setNames(df, replace(longnames[inds], is.na(inds), colnames(df)[is.na(inds)]))
```

Comment: Both of these examples give the correct output in the console but the setNames line does not seem to actually change df.
If I do names(df)<- setNames(....)  that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

you could make use of `adist` which is already vectorized:

```
a = which(!attr(adist(names(df),longnames,counts = T),'counts')[,,'sub'],T)

names(df)[a[,'row']] = longnames    #longnames[a[,'col']]

df
  text1 text2 a1 age a2 gender b1 postcode text3
1  nnnn     b      1        45          43    gg
2  uuuu     t      2        43           6    ll
3   ooo   eee      3        23           2    jj
```